# In T-SQL, What is the best way to find % of male customers by area

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Support I have a table with area, customer and customer's sex info and I want to find out % of male customers in each area. Whats the best way to come up with that?

```
create table temp(area_id  varchar(10),customer_id varchar(10),customer_sex varchar(10))
insert into temp select 1,1,'male'
insert into temp select 1,1,'male'
insert into temp select 1,1,'female'
insert into temp select 1,1,'female'
insert into temp select 2,1,'male'
insert into temp select 2,1,'female'
insert into temp select 2,1,'female'
insert into temp select 3,1,'male'
insert into temp select 3,1,'female'
insert into temp select 4,1,'male'
insert into temp select 5,1,'female'

select * from temp
```

The result should be like below:

[image]

Comment: get the count of  females and divide

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: You'll need to use the "group by" clause.

Comment: I think this should do it..     select area_id,
       male_customer_count = count(case when customer_sex = 'male' then '1' end) * 100.0 / count(*)
  from temp
 group by area_id

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
select x.area_id, x.total,  x.m, cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), x.m * 100.0 / x.total) as nvarchar(max)) + '%'
from
(
    select t.area_id, count(1) total, sum(iif(t.customer_sex = 'male', 1, 0)) m
    from @temp t
    group by t.area_id
)x
```

Comment: do you really need to use a derived table to get the number of males?

Answer (score 0):

Use IIF (Sqlserver 2012+) otherwise CASE, group by and sum of males /count all customers * 100
+ 0.0 to treat sum of males and all customer as float or decimal to get the correct result.

```
select area_id,count(customer_id) [Total Customers],
sum(iif(customer_sex='male',1,0)) [Total Males],
cast(cast(((sum(iif(customer_sex='male',1,0)) + 0.0) / (count(customer_sex) + 0.0)) * 100 as decimal(18,1)) as varchar(10)) + '%' [percentage of males]
from temp
group by area_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH x AS 
  (
  select 
    area_id
  , count(*) AS total_customers
  , SUM(CASE WHEN customer_sex = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_male_customers
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY area_id
  )
SELECT
  area_id
, total_customers
, total_male_customers
, CASE WHEN total_male_customers > 0 THEN CAST( (total_male_customers * 100.0) / total_customers AS DECIMAL(6,2)) ELSE 0 END AS Male_percentage
From x
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by and case will provide your results:

```
SELECT area_id, count(customer_id) as Total_Customers, Total_Male_Customers = sum(case when customer_sex = 'male' then 1 else 0 end),
    Format(sum(case when customer_sex = 'male' then 1 else 0 end)/(count(customer_id)*1.0),'P') as MaleCustomers 
FROM dbo.temp
GROUP BY area_id
HAVING sum(case when customer_sex = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Here if it is smaller dataset format is better else it has performance issues you can go with custom multiplication and concatenating % symbol.

Output as below:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
| area_id | Total_Customers | Total_Male_Customers | MaleCustomers |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
|       1 |               4 |                    2 | 50.00 %       |
|       2 |               3 |                    1 | 33.33 %       |
|       3 |               2 |                    1 | 50.00 %       |
|       4 |               1 |                    1 | 100.00 %      |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------+
```